# TinyMCE4 url list

Tags: javascript, plugins, tinymce, tinymce-4

I upgraded TinyMCE3 to TinyMCE4 in my CMS, but unfortunatelly [external_link_list_url](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x%3aexternal_link_list_url) and [external_image_list_url](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x%3aexternal_image_list_url) are not working.

Is there any plugin to get external_link_list_url and external_image_list_url from TinyMCE3 working again?

Comment: +1 good question (but i am not able to answer this one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of links, at least, I suspect that you're looking for the newer "link_list" parameter: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:link_list

Hard-coding the links in the configuration is the easy way, of course, but the "link" plugin is also clearly designed to accept a URL string in place of the list -- if it finds a string, it will make an AJAX request to the URL, and expects a JSON response in the same format as the link_list.

Now if only I could figure out how to dynamically update the contents of a TinyMCE 4.x ListBox...